# Why doesn't this div force the following divs to move the right?

Tags: html, css

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PsQBD/6/)

I am trying to use a div as an empty space div, so that the follow divs are moved further to the right.

Style

```
div.note {float:left;width:60px;  padding:0 0 0 50px;}
#buffer_div {width:150px;}
```

HTML

```
<div id="buffer_div"></div>
<div id="note-1" class="note">
    note display here1
</div>
<div id="note-2" class="note">
    note display here2
</div>
<div id="note-3" class="note">
    note display here3
</div>
```

As you can see from the jsFiddle, this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you do something like the following instead. It helps if you have as little markup as possible to achieve your goal and if all you want to do is add some space, a margin will do just fine.

```
<div id="note-1" class="note">
    note display here1
</div>
<div id="note-2" class="note">
    note display here2
</div>
<div id="note-3" class="note">
    note display here3
</div>
```

And in your CSS:

```
div.note {
    float:left;
    width:60px;
    padding:0 0 0 50px;
}

div#note-1{
    margin-left:150px;
}
```

If you wanted to actually use "#buffer_div" to have maybe some content like a side bar, you would need to add a float to that too. If you want a group of elements to display in a row, there is nothing wrong with adding a float to all of them.

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing, but I'd like to find another way because I'm doing some ajaxy stuff on the page and the first note will change dynamically.

Comment: This is the tidiest way to do it

Comment: I tried adding float - jsfiddle.net/PsQBD/12 but I don't think I'm doing it right because it's still not working?

Comment: If it will change dynamically, define a wrapper/container div for the notes, and put a margin-left on that. Much nicer than this 'buffer' div.

Comment: @ben, even if you are doing some dynamic stuff with the content of the div, and all of the positioning will be retained.

Comment: Here is an implementation of @bazmegakapa's suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/PsQBD/18/

Comment: Have a look at my answer. It will take care of the first child changing dinamically

Answer (score 1):

Your buffer div needs to float also.  Float and non-float elements do not interfere with each other.

Comment: @ben, the div has no content so it's not being rendered.

Comment: The div needs some filler content such as a non breaking space (`&nbsp;`) or it needs a height (in css, e.g.: `height: 1px`)

Comment: Add some content to your buffer div. even a &nbsp; and your second jsFiddle will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your div is empty, hence it takes no space. If you want to have a left spacing just remove that div and do

```
.note:first-child {margin-left: 150px}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way (unless there is a very good reason for a buffer div) would be make all the notes children of the buffer div and then change the "width" to "margin-left".